# Custom 403 error page in MVC4 not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, http-status-code-403, custom-error-pages

I have setup my `Web.config` in the following way to display custom 403 error pages but for some reason the page isnt shown - I still get the default error page!  The custom page is shown correctly for `404` which uses the same `ErrorController`

Web.Config

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
  <error redirect="~/Error/Forbidden" statusCode="403"  />
</customErrors>
```

ErrorController

```
public class ErrorController : BaseController
{
    public ViewResult Forbidden()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 403;  //you may want to set this to 200
        return View("Error403");
    }
}
```

Attribute that generates the 403:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AuthorizeEMAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `Forbidden` function be returning `ActionResult` and not `ViewResult`?

Comment: The function isnt even being hit!

Comment: So, your `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated` is the problem here, may be check `filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity` before the `if` to get more clue??

Comment: Why is that the problem? The if works correctly...

Comment: What is the answer to this question? I am facing the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Error.html" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
      <error redirect="~/Error/403.aspx" statusCode="403" />
      <error redirect="~/Error/404.aspx" statusCode="404" />
      <error redirect="~/Error/500.html" statusCode="500" />
    </customErrors>
```

Create page 403.aspx in root directory "Error"

```
     <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>403 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
    Server.ClearError();
Response.Status = "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.";
Response.StatusCode = 403;
         %>
    <div>
    <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```